# Installing Leviton IPS02 occupancy switch

Tags: wiring

I purchased a Leviton IPS02 motion occupancy switch to install in a lighting circuit.  The problem is, I pulled out the old switch and it is a 4 way switch with 5 wires ground included.  The Leviton switch has line, load and ground.  Can this be adapted for use?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved in the lighting circuit?

Comment: Also, is taking your occupancy switch back and getting a different one an option?

Comment: Obviously the light can be controlled from at least 2 other places.  Do you want the other switches to continue to work? **Does Code require you to have working switches in any of those locations?**